# Bird effect using Javascript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Please can someone suggest me a way to use the birds effect in the below website in some other website?? I am only concerned about the birds and nothing related to maps and other features in this website

[www.thewildernessdowntown.com](http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com)

Comment: That is a cool effect. The code is all right there — the JavaScript isn't even obfuscated — so you can look through it yourself and figure out how it works. Note that, if you copy the code to use in your own page, you could be violating copyright.

Answer (score 3):

I believe those are Boids, a method for simulating group animal motion developed by Craig Reynolds ([start reading here for background](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/)).

You can then look at the work of Daniel Shiffman, who has done a lot of fun things with Boids, including [this tutorial on making a simple 2D Boid system in javascript](http://processingjs.org/learning/topic/flocking/).

Once you understand these basics you can Google around to see how other people have used tools like Three.js (which that example you linked to uses) and the Boid concept. For example [this guy](http://blog.int3ractive.com/2012/05/fish-boids-threejs-demo.html) made an aquarium using Boids and Three.js and helpfully guides you to his source code on Github.

As for the actual birds, I imagine they are made up of a Three.js container Object3D which holds a body and two wings (which look like they are made of either planes-with-bitmaps or just raw triangles). The wings constantly rotate up and down, and the container object just rotates to point in whichever direction the Boid logic is taking it.

That is my educated guess anyway, and would be how I would recreate it.